# Internal compiler error in eclipse -npe

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I am suddenly getting this error from eclipse when compiling.

```
Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException at 
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.visit(AnnotationDiscoveryVisitor.java:61)
```

The project is an android project.  Any clues?  Don't want to do another eclipse reinstall!  Help!

Comment: Are you running any annotation processors?  (check project properties / Java Compiler / Annotation Processor / Factory Path).  Could it be that one of these are crashing?

Comment: Yes I am.  I removed the processors and the code compiled, but had runtime errors.  Now when I added the annotation processor back it is working again.

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but I had the same problem and also tried to find solution. Maybe it will help someone in the future:

The problem is that Eclipce is unable to compile files and it throws an exception. In my case the fix was:

1. Move for now all compiled sources (buildBin folders)
2. Move for now all custom builders (.externalToolBuilders) if you have ones, and all .settings folder
3. Restart Eclipse and let it build
4. Fix compilation problems :)
5. Paste back all previously removed files (to not loose any settings\builders)